# Logic behind the turn of player in Tic tac toe java

Tags: java, arrays, windows, if-statement, logic

I cannot understand logic behind deciding the turn. and also how the integer value is replaced by the character.

the source code of the program is from [full code](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tic-tac-toe-game-in-java/)

```
    // This game has two player x and O.
    // Here is the logic to decide the turn.
    if (board[numInput - 1].equals(
            String.valueOf(numInput))) {
        board[numInput - 1] = turn;

        if (turn.equals("X")) {
            turn = "O";
        } else {
            turn = "X";
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Sorry, but this site is not a discussion forum or programming tutorial site.
Please take the [tour], visit the [help] and read [Ask] to learn how to use this site effectively. 
Also read 
[Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/18157)

Answer (score 0):

variable board is string array so logic replace 1,2,3,.. and other numbers to X or O here:
'board[numInput - 1] = turn;'

first player is always 'X' after his first turn:
'if (turn.equals("X")) {' -> change player to 'O'
and after second player turn it back to 'X' and so on